# Maven build with XJC plugin fails on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

We are trying to build a maven project where we use the jaxb2-maven-plugin (version 1.4) to generate Java classes from some xsd files.
The configuration of one execution looks like this:

```
<execution>
<id>executionA</id>
<configuration>
<schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
<schemaFiles>path/A.xsd</schemaFiles>
<packageName>package.info.name</packageName>
<staleFile>target/generated-sources/A.jaxb</staleFile>
<bindingFiles>A.xjb</bindingFiles>
</configuration>
<goals>
<goal>xjc</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
```

We have, therefore, a A.xjb binding file which is placed in the default 'src/main/xjb' folder and which specifies some bindings.
For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
<jxb:globalBindings>
<xjc:simple />
<xjc:serializable uid="1" />
...
</jxb:globalBindings>
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../path/A.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
<jxb:schemaBindings>
...
</jxb:schemaBindings>
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name = 'XXX']">
...
</jxb:bindings>
...
</jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

The following error occurs when the build is executed on Jenkins:

> [INFO] — jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.4:xjc (executionA) @ schemas — [INFO]
>   Generating source... [INFO] parsing a schema... [ERROR]
>   file:/opt/home/diojenkins/workspace/project/schemas/src/main/xjb/A.xjb[12,118]
>   com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId:
>   file:/opt/home/diojenkins/workspace/project/schemas/src/main/xjb/A.xjb;
>   lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 118;
>   "file:/opt/home/diojenkins/workspace/project/schemas/src/main/path/A.xsd"
>   is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for
>   "file:/home/diojenkins/workspace/project/schemas/src/main/path/A.xsd"?
>   at
>   com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:598)
>   at
>   com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:592)
>   at
>   com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:246)
>   at
>   com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:375)
>   at
>   com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:136)
>   at
>   com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:98)
>   at
>   com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.transform(DOMForest.java:447)
>   at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:342)
>   at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:374)
>   at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:167) at
>   com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:113) at
>   com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:313) at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:314)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106) at
>   org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
>   at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136) at
>   hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71) at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121) at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49) at
>   hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326) at
>   hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [INFO] Failed to parse a
>   schema.

You may need to know that there exists a symbolic link between the /opt/home/diojenkins and /home/diojenkins so they are the same.

The error occurs only when the build is executed on Jenkins, if we build it in the Jenkins workspace with the same options it works just fine. Can anyone help us?

Comment: You should not be generating code into src -- you should generate it into target/generated. And, your schema should be under src/main/resources. Or, preferably, you should have your generated code in a separate module upon which your main code depends.

Comment: I don't realy see how relevant your comment is ? (The code generated is going into target/classes/package/info/name/... and the schema is place in the folder of the default configuration and this is a module that only generate code for other modules)
I insist on the fact that the build is working just fine but fails when running by Jenkins.

Comment: Did you find solution yet. I am having exact same issue

Comment: Yes, I did find a work around by giving the full path of the pom.xml in jenkins. 
Build > root pom > .../full/path/pom.xml

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me.